# How to add comment to <summary> for C# namespace by having namespaceDoc class file(not using SHFB)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xml-documentation

I want to add comment to C# namespace(I do not want to use [sandcastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB)). 
I have added empty NamespaceDoc class file to my project.

```
///<summary>
/// These are some the namespace comments 
///</summary>
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
class NamespaceDoc {
}
```

and when I build project, xml documentation appeared in the following format what is expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>MyNamespaceName</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:MyNamespaceName.NamespaceDoc">
            <summary>
             These are some the namespace comments 
            </summary>
        </member>        
    </members>
</doc>
```

But I want to write utility that will do following: during a build , if comments are in `<summary>` for class file `NamespaceDoc` , xml documentation file should be in the following format : `<summary>` for class `NamespaceDoc` will move to namespace `<summary>` and `NamespaceDoc` will disappear from xml documentation.
Here is desired format.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>
  <assembly>
    <name>MyNamespaceName</name>
  </assembly>
  <members>
    <member name="N:MyNamespaceName">
      <summary>
             These are some namespace comments
      </summary>
    </member>
  </members>
</doc>
```

Could you please help me to write such utility. Thank you.

Comment: How do you generate the xml code? can you provide a code example with us?

Comment: I do not generate xml code by myself. It is generated automatically during build.
Right clik on project=>Properties=>go to build tab, press check mark "XML documentation file" . And XML documentation file generated in chosen folder automatically during build

Answer (score 1):

I think it is hard to change the xml during the build. Therefore, I suggest that you can use c# code to modify the xml code.

Here is a code example.

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load("Mynamespace.xml");
    var result = doc.Descendants("member");
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        if(item.Attribute("name").Value== "T:Mynamespace.NamespaceDoc")
        {
            item.Attribute("name").Value= item.Attribute("name").Value.Replace(".NamespaceDoc", " ");
        }

    }
    doc.Save("Mynamespace.xml");
```